# GraphQL query looks ugly and has too arguments many with paginate and filter on many nested fields

Tags: graphql

If you have a graphql query like this

```
query findAllNotes() {
    comments: [Comment]!
}
```

How do you paginate and filter the notes and comments without having ugly looking and lengthy argument lists?
This problem worsens as the nest level increases.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any "**fancy**" option here. You create an `input` type and then assign it to the corresponding `query` or `mutation`. Just like `REST`, you return the **n** values for each page. If the user does not provide the `pageId` arg, then you can return by default the first **n** values, like first 10 or 20 objects.